# How can I only parse the first HTML block from multiple blocks, if they all contain the same class-name?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I need to parse info from a site, on this site, there are 2 blocks, "Today" and "Yesterday", and they have the same class name of `standard-box standard-list`.
How can I *only* parse the *first* block (under "Today") in a row, without extracting the inform from "Yesterday", if they both contain the same class-name?

Here is my code:

```py
import requests


url_news = "https://www.123.org/"
response = requests.get(url_news)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
items = soup.findAll("div", class_="standard-box standard-list")
news_info = []
for item in items:
    news_info.append({
        "title": item.find("div", class_="newstext",).text,
        "link": item.find("a", class_="newsline article").get("href")
    })
```

Comment: Please share the URL

Comment: hltv.org, i try to parse news

Comment: Yes,i got all info about titles what i need

Comment: Can i do like,last point of my parsed info need to be <h2> <Yesterday>?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Post the html which you are trying to scrape (not the whole thing!  Just the bit you are trying to identify) if the question is 'how do I get this particular tag from this html'.

Comment: <div class="standard-box standard-list">
i need to scrape this html block, which names Today, but block Yesterday has the same tag

Comment: @makim I have edited your question to better clarify the problem, I hope this was your intention. Also, please take a minute to read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running your provided code, I don't get an output for `items`. However, you said that you do, so:

If you only want to get the data under "Today", you can use `.find()` instead of `.find_all()`, since `.find()` will only return the *first* found tag -- which is "Today" and not the other tags.

So, instead of:

```
items = soup.findAll("div", class_="standard-box standard-list")
```

Use:

```
items = soup.find("div", class_="standard-box standard-list")
```

Additionally, to find the link, I needed to access the *attribute* using `tag-name[attribute]`. Here is working code:

```
news_info = []
items = soup.find("div", class_="standard-box standard-list")
for item in items:
    news_info.append(
        {"title": item.find("div", class_="newstext").text, "link": item["href"]}
    )

print(news_info)
```

Output:

```
[{'title': 'NIP crack top 3 ranking for the first time in 5 years', 'link': 'https://www.hltv.org/news/32545/nip-crack-top-3-ranking-for-the-first-time-in-5-years'}, {'title': 'Fessor joins Astralis Talent', 'link': 'https://www.hltv.org/news/32544/fessor-joins-astralis-talent'}, {'title': 'Grashog joins AGO', 'link': 'https://www.hltv.org/news/32542/grashog-joins-ago'}, {'title': 'ISSAA parts ways with Eternal Fire', 'link': 'https://www.hltv.org/news/32543/issaa-parts-ways-with-eternal-fire'}, {'title': 'BLAST Premier Fall Showdown Fantasy live', 'link': 'https://www.hltv.org/news/32541/blast-premier-fall-showdown-fantasy-live'}, {'title': 'FURIA win IEM Fall NA, EG claim final Major Legends spot', 'link': 'https://www.hltv.org/news/32540/furia-win-iem-fall-na-eg-claim-final-major-legends-spot'}]
```

Comment: Thank you,i appreciate it.